# DRCSIM: Fat head: Random head parts have too large moments of inertia (and probably mass)

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are 7 head parts that have dubious mass and moment of inertia values:

```
left camera frame
right camera frame
center_top_led_frame
center_bottom_led_frame
left_led_frame
right_led_frame
head_imu_link
```

They all have mass = 0.1 and principal moments of inertia of 0.001.
Collectively they weigh 0.7kg. The main head weighs only double that, 1.4kg, and the spinning Hokuyo weighs an order of magnitude less: 0.057664.
Collectively, the principal moments of inertia are 0.007.
This is almost double the head principal moments of inertia, around 0.004.

Since these are all fixed on the head, the masses can be reduced until the head and all its parts has the right total weight, and the principal moments of inertia should be made tiny (1e-6).

Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2150/drcsim:-fat-head:-random-head-parts-have-too-large-moments-of-inertia-(and-probably-mass)./) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

thanks, addressing in [pull reuest #157](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/157/inertia-updates/diff#chg-ros/multisense_sl_description/urdf/multisense_sl.urdf)

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0